# How to insert npm uniqid modules in mysql database using nodejs. when i put on my code it display an error "TypeError: uniqid is not a function"

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs with express and mysql. when i submit a form i found an error "uniqid is not a function".

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var uniqid = require('uniqid');
var db = require('../db');

router.post('/create',function(req,res,next){
    var full_name = req.body.fullname;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password= req.body.password;
    var mobile_no = req.body.mobile_no;    
    var uniqid = uniqid();

    var insert_query = `INSERT INTO users (user_uid,full_name,email,mobile_no,password) VALUES ("${uniqid}","${full_name}","${email}","${mobile_no}","${password}") `;

    db.query(insert_query,function(err,result){
      if(err) throw err;
      res.redirect('/signup');
   });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `var uniqid = uniqid();` Are you sure about that variable name ?

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding the `uniqid` module with the value from `uniqid()`

```
var uniqid = require('uniqid');
...
var uniqid = uniqid();
```

While it might work on the first execution<sup>1</sup>, subsequent calls will fail with that error "uniqid is not a function"

Change the name and use es6 `let/const` instead of `var`

```
const uniqid = require('uniqid');
...
const newId = uniqid();
const insert_query = `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ("${newId}"...) `;
```

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*It doesn't, see Klaycon comment below*</sub>

Comment: It won't work on the first execution due to variable hoisting in that callback's function scope - `uniqid` is declared, hiding the module, then the undefined value is attempted to be called as a function

Comment: i using your method it successfully inserted in database, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this code for example :

```js
var foo = () => "test"

function test() {
  var foo = foo()
}

test()
```

As you can see, it has the same error you have. This is because you are naming your local variable like your global variable.

What happens is what is called [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). When the function gets executed, it declares `foo` as a variable local to the current function execution context *before* setting it any value.

Then the engine tries to set its value with `foo()`, but at that time `foo` is a local variable, not the global one, and its value is `undefined`.

And obviously, `undefined` is not a function, hence the error, "foo is not a function".

tl;dr: be careful when naming your variables (and use `let`/`const`).